# WCF rest service for list - json not working

Tags: json, wcf, rest

My wcf reset service has only 2 contracts, one is working always and the other did not work.

Service Code:

```
Public Class BasicServ
     Implements IBasicServ

        Public Function DoWork() Implements IBasicServ.DoWork
            Return "Working"
        End Function

        Function Authorize(ByVal id As String, ByVal pw As String) Implements IBasicServ.Authorize
            Dim c As New List(Of Guid)
            For i = 0 To 10
                c.Add(Guid.NewGuid)
            Next
            Return c
            'Return Guid.NewGuid
        End Function
    End Class
```

Contract File code:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IBasicServ

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="test/", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Function DoWork()

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="Authorize/{id}/{pw}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Function Authorize(ByVal id As String, ByVal pw As String)


End Interface
```

Web Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics> 
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messagelistener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                      initializeData="d:\logs\myMessages.svclog"></add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics> 

    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
     <diagnostics>
       <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
                        logMalformedMessages="true"
                        maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">         
       </messageLogging>
     </diagnostics>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehav" name="AssistantWcf.BasicServ">
        <endpoint address="auth" behaviorConfiguration="EndBehav" binding="webHttpBinding" name="endpointname" contract="AssistantWcf.IBasicServ" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EndBehav">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServBehav">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

While debugging/testing, I found that, if I return only 1 GUID in Authoriza method, it is working, but when I am sending a list of GUID, it is not working, and the SVClog file is not getting created.  Could you please help me understand WCF REST service better. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `WebHttpBinding`? Could you post your configuration?

Comment: My mistake, added the webconfig file code.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know whether or not you can return a GUID, so for testing purpose, maybe make sure that it is returned as a string but shouldn't your interface and function define that you want a list? i.e. Function Authorize(ByVal id As String, ByVal pw As String) As List (Of String).

Comment: Yup that is working, but when I am sending it as only a GUID not list, it worked although I did not specify the return type, could you please post as answer and clarify if possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From above comments and few experiments, the solution for the question is that a return type is not compulsory if it is string, but if anything else, return type must be specified. Better if return type is provided always.